# How to instantiate subclass of UITableViewController subclass

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, polymorphism, swift4

I have a class `ParentTableVC` extends `UITableViewController`.

```
class ParentTableVC: UITableViewController{

    ...

    // method must be overriden in base class
    func getDataList(page: Int){
        preconditionFailure("This method must be overriden")
    }

}
```

and a child class of `ParentTableVC` which overrides `getDataList()`

```
class ChildVC: ParentTableVC {

        override func getDataList(page: Int){
            print("This is the Data")
        }

}
```

I am instantiating ParentTableVC like this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListVC")
```

ListVC is identifier for `ParentTableVC` in Storyboard

How can I instantiate ChildVC?

Comment: You may have to create a View Controller scene in storyboard for each and every child view controllers. I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class of a viewcontroller in the storyboards by selecting the viewcontroller then in the identity inspector specify your custom class in the Class field like this: [image]

Now when you instantiate the viewcontroller that would be your custom viewcontroller that you specified in the storyboards.

Comment: Cannot do this because ParentTableVC have multiple children sharing this one view

Comment: BTW, Inheritance is old now. Since you are using Swift I would recommend using protocol oriented programming instead of object oriented programming to achieve this.

Comment: In protocol oriented programming you need to declare a protocol with method ```getDataList```. Now your child vcs don't need to inherit from the parent. They simply inherit directly from UITableViewController and provides their own ```getDataList``` implementation by confirming to the protocol.